# Boton de guardar que sirva para actualizar

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing, botón, crud

recurro a uds ya que tengo una duda y no se me ocurre nada para resolverla. Les comento. Estoy haciend un CRUD en Java con la BD Mysql. He hecho casi todos los botones, solo me falta el de actualizar. Resulta y pasa que quiero que el boton de **Guardar** me sirva también para actualizar los campos. Es decir que yo al seleccionar un campo de la tabla este me lo cargue en los JFields para luego modificarlos y guardar los con el mismo botón sin necesidad de crear uno nuevo.

tengo el siguiente ejemplo.

```
private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    terceros objTercero = new terceros();
    String nombres = txtNombres.getText();
    String apellidos = txtApellidos.getText();
    int telefono = Integer.parseInt(txtTelefono.getText());
    int id = Integer.parseInt(txtId.getText());

    if(id == 0){
        boolean resultado = objTercero.insertartercero(nombres,apellidos,telefono);
        if(resultado == true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se inserto un nuevo registro");
            cargarTabla();
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al insertar");
        }
    }else{
        boolean resultado = objTercero.actualizartercero(id, nombres,apellidos,telefono);
        if(resultado == true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se inserto un nuevo registro");
            cargarTabla();
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al insertar");
        }    

    }
```

Como veran hay una condicion en la cual el id = 0, en esa tabla el ID no se suministra ya que es autoincrementable. Pero en la tabla que estoy haciendo el ID es la identificación del usuario así que no lo puedo dejar en 0. Me gustaría por favor que me ayudaran a pensar en una condición parecidad a la anterior.

Muchas Gracias!

---

gracias por tu respuesta.

He pensando en algo y se parece un poco en lo que dices. La idea que tengo  es que, antes de insertar el dato, poner una sentencia que me evalúe si el id existe en la BD, si es así que me actualice el registro, de lo contrario que me guarde el registro. Pero el problema es que cuando hago la consulta es decir. Eje: String consulta = "Selec fron...";. Luego de eso quiero que en una variable de tipo booleano me almacene el resultado. Si la consulta se ejecutó entonces que me envíe un valor booleano  para luego programar ese valor en un condicional. Si es true (osea que el dato está en la BD) me actualice y si no  que me guarde el valor. No he podido hacer lo del tipo booleano. Me podrías ayudar por favor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando vas a editar algo, primero tienes que saber que es, por tanto deberias haber accedido a la base de datos primeramente para obtener lo que quieres editar y dentro de esos datos viene el **ID**, en el metodo **Guardar** puedes preguntar por el **ID** del objeto y si es mayor que 0 entonces ya es un valor que existe en la base datos y dentro de esa condicion lo salvas.

```
if(id > 0){
    // codigo de actualizar
}else{
   // codigo de guardar
}
```

Espero entiendas lo que quiero decir.

Para saber si la consulta ejecutada tiene valores o no, puedes usar esto

```
if(query.first()){
  //consulta vacia
}else{
  //consulta con algun valor
}
```

Comment: Hola Jose por favor no añadas varias respuestas, añade una que ayude a resolver el problema, revisa [answer].Saludos.

Comment: Voy a intentarlo, te comento si algo. Gracias por la ayuda!